# Outputs to CloudFormation query params

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, jmespath

Say I have the following output from querying a CloudFormation stack:

```
$ aws cloudformation describe-stacks --stack-name my-stack --query "Stacks[0].Outputs[*]"
[
    {
        "OutputKey": "VPC",
        "OutputValue": "vpc-123abcd"
    },
    {
        "OutputKey": "SubnetAZ2",
        "OutputValue": "subnet-456efgh"
    },
    {
        "OutputKey": "SubnetAZ1",
        "OutputValue": "subnet-789ijkl"
    },
    {
        "OutputKey": "PrivateSubnetAZ2",
        "OutputValue": "subnet-012mnop"
    },
    {
        "OutputKey": "PrivateSubnetAZ1",
        "OutputValue": "subnet-345qrst"
    }
]
```

I would like to format this output into a string which can be used in a `aws cloudformation create-stack` command, like this:

```
aws cloudformation create-stack \
  ...
  --parameters "ParameterKey=VPC,ParameterValue=vpc-123abcd ParameterKey=SubnetAZ2,..."
```

**Question**: How can I convert a list of objects (like the one above) to a formatted string (like the one above) with JMESPath?

It seems like it should be possible by using [map](https://jmespath.org/specification.html#map), something down the lines of:

```
--query Stacks[0].Outputs[*].{ParameterKey: OutputKey, ParameterValue: OutputValue} | map([&ParameterKey,&ParameterValue], @)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
aws cloudformation describe-stacks --stack-name <stack-name> --query "Stacks[0].Outputs[*].[join(',', [join('=',['ParameterKey', OutputKey]), join('=',['ParameterValue', OutputValue])])] | join(' ', [])" --output text
```

Its rather unreadable, but JMESPath syntax is far from pretty.  Basically, the idea is that using `join` you contract the entire string in the format required.

First you construct inner parts (e.g. `ParameterKey=VPC` and `ParameterValue=vpc-123abcd`), which then you join into `ParameterKey=VPC,ParameterValue=vpc-123abcd`. Finally you join all them together to construct  `ParameterKey=VPC,ParameterValue=vpc-123abcd ParameterKey=SubnetAZ2,ParameterValue=subnet-456efgh`